# pyspark regexp_replace replacing multiple values in a column

Tags: pyspark, regexp-replace

I have the url `https://www.youcustomizeit.com/p/Equations-Kids-Backpack-Personalized/301793\r` in dataset. I want to remove `https://` at the start of the string and `\r` at the end of the string.

Creating dataframe to replicate the issue

`c = spark.createDataFrame([('https://www.youcustomizeit.com/p/Equations-Kids-Backpack-Personalized/301793\r',)], ['str'])`

I tried below regexp_replace with pipe function. But it is not working as expected.

`c.select(F.regexp_replace('str', 'https:// | \\r', '')).first()`

Actual output:
`www.youcuomizei.comEquaion-Kid-Backack-Peronalized301793`

Expected output:
`www.youcustomizeit.com/p/Equations-Kids-Backpack-Personalized/301793`

Comment: I added an extra space before and after pipe. Once I removed that it worked

`c.select(F.regexp_replace("str", "https://|[\\r]","")).first()`

Answer (score 0):

the "backslash"r (\r) is not showing in your original spark.createDataFrame object because you have to escape it. so your spark.createDataFrame should be. please note the double backslashes

```
c = spark.createDataFrame([("https://www.youcustomizeit.com/p/Equations-Kids-Backpack-Personalized/301793\\r",)], ['str'])
```

which will give this output:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|str                                                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|https://www.youcustomizeit.com/p/Equations-Kids-Backpack-Personalized/301793\r|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

your regex `https://|[\\r]` will not remove the `\r` . the regex should be

```
c = (c
    .withColumn("str", F.regexp_replace("str", "https://|[\\\\]r", "")) 
)
```

which will give this output:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|str                                                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|www.youcustomizeit.com/p/Equations-Kids-Backpack-Personalized/301793|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```